# Store MySQL query result into a two-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have not seen a similar question so I'm asking a new one. I'm also experimenting with using loops and arrays, so apologies if this is a really dumb question or really bad code. I was able to do achieve my desired result with about 50 more lines of code, but it was even more inelegant (I basically had each query in a hardcoded line, instead of using variable). Hence, I am trying to learn how to code this a bit more neatly to make it more efficient. I might be going down the wrong path though...

I have a table with the following basic structure:

```
[id / username / email / content / side / category / rating]
```

Side can either be "yes" or "no" and Category can either be "red", "blue" or "green". These  are restricted in the submission form.

I'm trying to execute the following query in a loop to pull all the required data and store them into a two-dimensional variable in php:

```
$dialecticSides = array("yes","no");
$numberSides = 2;
$dialecticRow = array("red","blue","green");
$numberRows = 3;

$dialectic_queryString = $dialectic_mysqlQuery = $dialectic_sqlResult = $dialectic_totalRows = array();

for($x=0;$x<$numberSides;$x++) {
    for ($y=0;$y<$numberRows;$y++) {        
        $dialectic_queryString[$x][$y] = "SELECT * FROM ". $dialectic_sqlTable ." WHERE side = '" . $dialecticSides[$x]. "' AND category = '". $dialecticRow[$y]."' ORDER BY rating DESC";
        $dialectic_mysqlQuery[$x][$y] = mysql_query($dialectic_queryString[$x][$y], $commenting_conn) or die(mysql_error());
        $dialectic_sqlResult[$x][$y] = mysql_fetch_assoc($dialectic_mysqlQuery[$x][$y]);
        $dialectic_totalRows[$x][$y] = mysql_num_rows($dialectic_sqlResult[$x][$y]);

        var_dump($dialectic_sqlResult);
    }
}
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
             (
               all the comments which are in row 0 (yes) and side 0 (red)
             )
          [1] => Array
             (
               all the comments which are in row 0 (yes) and side 1 (blue)
             )
          [2] => Array
             (
               all the comments which are in row 0 (yes) and side 2 (green)
             )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
          [0] => Array
             (
                all the comments which are in row 1 (no) and side 0 (red)
             )
          [1] => Array
             (
               all comments which are in row 1 (no) and side 1 (blue)
             )
          [2] => Array
             (
               all the comments which are in row 1 (no) and side 2 (green)
             )
        )
)
```

Essentially, if I want to know if what I'm doing makes any sense at all or if I should give up and go back to hardcoding the queries to different result variables.

My query is failing - the output of the query is null. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

==== SOLVED it ====

```
for($x=0;$x<$numberSides;$x++) {
for ($y=0;$y<$numberRows;$y++) {        
    $queryString[$x][$y] = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE topic_id = '{$topicid}' AND side = '{$x}' AND row = '{$y}'";
    $result[$x][$y] = mysqli_query($db_connection,$queryString[$x][$y]) or die(mysqli_error($db_connection));
    while($eachcomment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[$x][$y])) {
        $array[$x][$y][] = $eachcomment;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling `mysql_num_rows()` on the `$dialectic_sqlResult` (which is an array). You should instead call it on `$dialectic_mysqlQuery` (which is a result resource).

Comment: Thanks @msound . I tried replacing `$dialectic_sqlResult` with `$dialectic_mysqlQuery` as suggested  but received a similar error: "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in lineXXX". The only difference now is that instead of returning FALSE, it is returning NULL. Is this because of the way I'm calling the results into a two-dimensional array?

Comment: Since you have the result array, why don't you just find totalRows using `count($dialectic_sqlResult[$x][$y])`

Comment: You said "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in lineXXX". That means your query execution mysql_query() failed. Just before calling mysql_query(), print the query and share it here.

Comment: Your table has id, username, etc.  What is in the "array of all the comments"?

Comment: Thanks @dcromley for your reply below. I'll try it out. Just to answer your question so it's not hanging - I would like all the [id, username, email, content, side and category] values that fit the condition [that fit the condition of side=yes and category=red] to all be in the "array of all comments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to put your queries etc. into arrays.
You want just one query.
Define your 2 arrays to get your output rows and columns:

```
$rowarray = array("yes" => 0, "no" => 1); // 2 rows?
$colarray = array("red" => 0, "blue" => 1, "green" => 2); // 3 cols?
```

Initialize your output array:

```
$outputarray = array(array('', '', ''), array('', '', ''));
```

Get $result from your query.

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

(Don't have a WHERE clause)
Then process the results:

```
while (($qrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))<>NULL) {
```

$qrow is an associative array: 'side' => 'yes', 'category' => 'red', etc.
For each qrow, get the output row and col:

```
$row = $rowarray[$qrow['side']];
$col = $colarray[$qrow['category']]
```

At this point you can accumulate what you want into $outputarray:

```
$outputarray[$row][$col] .= $qrow['comments'];
```

This is the end of your "while" loop:

```
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @dcromley ! That worked for me. 
If I wanted to add other fields from the table into my $outputarray, how should I do it? What I'd like to do is `$outputarray[$row][$col] .= $qrow['username','email','comments'];` but I know that this is incorrect.  I tried this: 
`$outputarray[$row][$col] .= array($qrow['username'],$qrow['email'], $qrow['comments']);`
but it failed: 
`Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array`
 
I checked [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) but could not find a way to reference multiple fields in the associative array.

Comment: @GK79 I think it's merely `.= $qrow['username'] . $qrow['email'] . $qrow['comments'];` But I'm not at home.  (Please accept answer). Thanks, @msound

Comment: Unfortunately I think that just creates a superlong string with all the fields concatenated, and it is not possible to subsequently call each field separately....

Comment: @GK79 Maybe this: (THREE dimensional array) `$outputarray[$row][$col] = array('username' => $qrow['username'], 'email' => $qrow['email'] etc.` Then `$onefield = $outputarray[1][2]['email']` ?

Comment: how would I initialise the $outputarray for a 3D array with 9 fields?

Comment: @GK79 - This might get lengthy. Hit dcromley to get my email address.

Comment: Figured it out @dcromley - but thanks!
`for($x=0;$x<$numberSides;$x++) {
for ($y=0;$y<$numberRows;$y++) {        
    $queryString[$x][$y] = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE topic_id = '{$topicid}' AND side = '{$x}' AND row = '{$y}'";
    $result[$x][$y] = mysqli_query($db_connection,$queryString[$x][$y]) or die(mysqli_error($db_connection));
    while($eachcomment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result[$x][$y])) {
        $array[$x][$y][] = $eachcomment;
    }
}`